# How to pass asyncio.get_event_loop() to quart in command line?

Tags: heroku, python-asyncio, telethon, quart, hypercorn

In a [doc](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/pull/1207) they passed event loop to quart.
Need to call async method in route handler.

How to change this to command line for heroku?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop=asyncio.get_event_loop()
    app.run(loop=loop)
```

I tried

```
web: hypercorn  -b 0.0.0.0:${PORT} --workers=1 telegram:app -k asyncio
```

But still got

```
2019-06-22 10:00:45.047703 app[web.1]:  Task <Task pending coro=<ASGIWebsocketConnection.handle_websocket() running at /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/quart/asgi.py:135> cb=[_wait.<locals>._on_completion() at /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/asyncio/tasks.py:440]> got Future <Future pending> attached to a different loop
2019-06-22 10:00:45.048350 app[web.1]:  Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-06-22 10:00:45.048395 app[web.1]:  File "/app/tele.py", line 34, in create_contact
2019-06-22 10:00:45.048399 app[web.1]:  contacts =await client2(functions.contacts.ImportContactsRequest([contact]))
2019-06-22 10:00:45.048410 app[web.1]:  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telethon/client/users.py", line 60, in __call__
2019-06-22 10:00:45.048414 app[web.1]:  result = await future
2019-06-22 10:00:45.048458 app[web.1]:  RuntimeError: Task <Task pending coro=<ASGIWebsocketConnection.handle_websocket() running at /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/quart/asgi.py:135> cb=[_wait.<locals>._on_completion() at /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/asyncio/tasks.py:440]> got Future <Future pending> attached to a different loop
```

Follow up question for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56689198/runtimeerror-task-got-future-future-pending-attached-to-a-different-loop/56704621#56704621)

---

[How to obtain an event loop from Quart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48971586) 
here says quart's app.run() uses  the default event loop created by asyncio for the main thread
Then why they pass the loop?

Comment: Any minimal repo to reproduce the issue?

Comment: https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/pull/1207
with heroku

Comment: Shouldn't the last two lines be inside a `if __name__ == '__main__':`?

Comment: Yes , its inside

Comment: Was not in your pull request, that's why asked

Comment: Need to call async method in route handler.

Answer (score 3):

Because `hypercorn` will not go inside `if __main__`, you need to create loop beforehand and set it as default:

```py
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
# do whatever you want, e.g.: 
# loop.create_task(background())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()  # now unnecessary
    app.run(loop=loop)

# should be just
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: Will hypercorn use the loop we created?

Comment: Need to call async method in route handler.

Answer (score 1):

Opening client inside [before_serving](https://pgjones.gitlab.io/quart/startup_shutdown.html) solved this.